# Image size independent shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I'm trying to create a shader for an image material that draws a circle regardless of the aspect ratio of the image itself.

In Shadertoy (hlsl) I can do the following to create a round circle, regardless of aspect ratio:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    uv -= 0.5;
    uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y; // < this compensates for the aspect ratio

    float l = length(uv);
    float s = smoothstep(0.5, 0.55, l);

    vec4 col = vec4(s);
    fragColor = vec4(col);
}
```

Which gives the following output [image: circular circle]

If I remove the line `uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;` the circle will warp based on the current aspect ratio.

Now I want to create the same effect in Unity, so I tried the (to me seemingly) same approach.
`_MainTex_TexelSize` contains the width/height of the texture (from the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html?_ga=2.219814489.1377353842.1581941618-1621210.1581941618)):

> {TextureName}_TexelSize - a float4 property contains texture size information:
>   - x contains 1.0/width
>   - y contains 1.0/height
>   - z contains width
>   - w contains height

```
Shader "Unlit/Shader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.uv -= 0.5;
                o.uv.x *= _MainTex_TexelSize.z / _MainTex_TexelSize.w;
                return o;
            }

            float DrawCircle(float2 uv, float radius, float fallOff)
            {
                float d = length(uv);
                return smoothstep(radius, fallOff, d);
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                float c = DrawCircle(i.uv, 0.5, 0.55);
                col = lerp(col, fixed4(1,0,0,1), c);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The shader compiles as is, but the circle will still stretch based on the aspect ratio of the image.
[image: stretched circle]

I thought this may be due to the way the uv's are set up using `o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);` so I tried dividing that by the image's size:

```
o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
o.uv / _MainTex_TexelSize.zw;
o.uv -= 0.5;
```

However this did nothing

and setting up the uv's differently like so

```
o.uv = v.uv / _MainTex_TexelSize.zw;
o.uv / _MainTex_TexelSize.zw;
o.uv -= 0.5;
```

results in the circle's center moving to the upper right, but still warp when the aspect ratio change.

What step am I missing/doing wrong to get the aspect ratio independent result like I get in shadertoy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the input texture `_MainTex` has nothing to do with the aspect ratio of the output*. In the shadertoy example that output is the screen, and `iResolution` gives you the screen dimensions (the equivalent in unity is `_ScreenParams`).
 If you want to draw a quad that is not full screen, you have to match the quad aspect ratio with the `_MainTex` aspect ratio to use `_MainTex_TexelSize`, or else just provide the aspect ratio or dimensions in a shader property (that is basically what `_ScreenParams` does):

```
float _Aspect;    
fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    i.uv -= .5;     
    i.uv.x *= _Aspect;

    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv); 

    float c = DrawCircle(i.uv, .5, .55);        
    col = lerp(col, fixed4(1,0,0,1), c);    
    return col;
}
```

You could calculate the aspect ratio with [derivatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-ddx). Here dx and dy are the amount of uv change per pixel. This would also be useful if you want to have, for example, `fallOff` always be 10 pixels.

```
fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    i.uv -= .5; 
    float dx = ddx(i.uv.x);
    float dy = ddy(i.uv.y);
    float aspect = dy/dx;
    i.uv.x *= aspect;

    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv); 

    float c = DrawCircle(i.uv, .5, .55);
    col = lerp(col, fixed4(1,0,0,1), c);
    return col;
}
```